# Is there an implement of focal loss for regression problem?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, loss-function

Proposed in RetinaNet, Focal Loss is a efficient solution to class imbalance for classification problem. But data imbalance can also occur in  regression problem. Is there any implementation of focal loss in regression problem?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.